# The Derivative of a Vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, vectors, transpose

It is stated in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaiiyIsbNdI&t=537) that some books attempt to define the derivative of a vector, with the added caveat that tensor notation is a much better approach.  Presumably, this is a different concept than the derivative of a vector-valued function, as the latter is uncontroversial and ubiquitous.  What is this unpalatable process used by such books to take the derivative of a vector, and a vector transposed?

Comment: I didn't click on the youtube link, but as a general comment derivatives are always based on changes in functions, which are then taken to the limit as some parameter approaches zero. Notation doesn't change this, it's more a matter of convenience.

Comment: The best framework for this is geometric algebra or Clifford Algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked video appears to be a discussion about minimizing 
$$\eqalign{ f(x) &= \tfrac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb}$$
Here's how one might solve it using matrix notation.

First find the differential and gradient of the function.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \tfrac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^Tx \cr
df &= \tfrac{1}{2}(dx^TAx+x^TA\,dx) - b^Tdx \cr
  &= (x^TA -b^T)\,dx \cr
  &= (Ax-b)^T\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= Ax - b \cr
}$$
Then set the gradient to zero and solve
$$(Ax-b)=0 \implies x=A^{-1}b$$
So it's not really as bad as the lecturer is making it out to be.

The same calculation in index/tensor notation looks like
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \tfrac{1}{2}x_iA_{ij}x_j - b_ix_i \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(\delta_{ik}A_{ij}x_j+x_iA_{ij}\delta_{jk}) - b_i\delta_{ik} \cr
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(A_{kj}x_j+x_iA_{ik}) - b_k \cr
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(A_{kj}x_j+A_{ki}^Tx_i) - b_k \cr
 &= A_{kj}x_j - b_k \cr
}$$
For dealing with scalars, vectors, and matrices (as in this problem) the two notations are roughly equivalent. The real power of index/tensor notation is in dealing with higher-order tensors.

Comment: Why does $dx^TAx = x^TAdx$?

Comment: Because of two things: 1) $A=A^T$ and 2) for real vectors $x^Ty=y^Tx$